# Desktop Ubuntu-20.04.3 iptables problem

Tags: iptables, snort

I want to test some iptables rules
the rule is to deny all outbound traffic except DNS.
so I changed the OUTPUT default rule of filter table to DROP using this command.

```
sudo iptables -t filter -P OUTPUT DROP
```

then I appended this rule to ACCEPT DNS traffic.

```
sudo iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -o ens33 -j ACCEPT
```

and I run this command to test the policy.

```
nslookup google.com
```

and before running this command I run wireshark on my vm and host.
then nslookup command toke some time and gave me this message.

> connection timed out; no servers could be reached

and wireshark (on vm and on host) did not captcher any packets.

so I deleted this rule and added another one.

```
sudo iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

and did the same thing as before.
the same message appear again but wireshark (on vm and on host) captcher the packets (the request and response).

then I deleted this rule and added the next rule.

```
sudo iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p udp -j ACCEPT
```

and did the same thing as before.
this time nslookup command return with the result and wireshark captcher the packets.

So why this happen?

before these tests I installed snort (on a different vm) and I tried to drop some packets but it didn't.
the packets are logged but not dropped.
I don't know if these cases are related or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is really a good one. There are no error messages and everything looks correct with various iptables inquiry tools.

However, you need to allow traffic to/from the local loopback interface, lo. So you need one other rule. By the way, you do not need the `-t filter` part. So, and modified for my test computer network interface, and I use tcpdump instead of wireshark, and I have two occurrences running, one on lo and one on my NIC:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
nslookup google.com
Server:         127.0.0.53     <<<<<<< NOTE:
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 142.251.33.78
Name:   google.com
Address: 2607:f8b0:400a:806::200e
```

and:

```
doug@s19:~/iptables/tmp$ cat c06.txt
2021-11-21 09:41:07.851723 IP 192.168.111.136.37847 > 192.168.111.1.53: 52661+ [1au] A? google.com. (39)
2021-11-21 09:41:07.879409 IP 192.168.111.1.53 > 192.168.111.136.37847: 52661 1/0/1 A 142.251.33.78 (55)
2021-11-21 09:41:07.884300 IP 192.168.111.136.52279 > 192.168.111.1.53: 58740+ [1au] AAAA? google.com. (39)
2021-11-21 09:41:07.899157 IP 192.168.111.1.53 > 192.168.111.136.52279: 58740 1/0/1 AAAA 2607:f8b0:400a:806::200e (67)
```

and:

```
doug@s19:~/iptables/tmp$ cat l01.txt
2021-11-21 09:41:07.850815 IP 127.0.0.1.51470 > 127.0.0.1.51470: UDP, length 1
2021-11-21 09:41:07.851625 IP 127.0.0.1.46738 > 127.0.0.53.53: 31736+ A? google.com. (28)
2021-11-21 09:41:07.879486 IP 127.0.0.53.53 > 127.0.0.1.46738: 31736 1/0/0 A 142.251.33.78 (44)
2021-11-21 09:41:07.884223 IP 127.0.0.1.35841 > 127.0.0.53.53: 58878+ AAAA? google.com. (28)
2021-11-21 09:41:07.899259 IP 127.0.0.53.53 > 127.0.0.1.35841: 58878 1/0/0 AAAA 2607:f8b0:400a:806::200e (56)
```

So why does the server appear to be local? By default Ubuntu runs a local resolver for buffering dns records and such:

```
doug@s19:~$ sudo ss -tulpn | grep ":53"
Netid  State  Recv-Q  Send-Q         Local Address:Port  Peer Address:Port                         Process
udp    UNCONN  0       0              127.0.0.53%lo:53            0.0.0.0:*      users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=834,fd=12))
tcp    LISTEN  0       4096           127.0.0.53%lo:53            0.0.0.0:*      users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=834,fd=13))
```

see also results from `sudo systemctl status systemd-resolved` and the [related man pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/systemd-resolved.service.8.html).

Comment: Thank you very much
I did as you said and it worked

but nslookup response message is not what I expected
could you please explain why nslookup response message says that the server is my loopback "127.0.0.53" ?
I expected 8.8.8.8
I tried many domains and still the server is my loopback "127.0.0.53"
what happens behind the scene ?

Comment: answer edited with a reply to your comment.